# Create ordered index on asynchronous document creation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a comment system with advanced lazy loading capabilities on the client like so:

```
comment 1
 |
[load more]
 | 
comment 7
 |
comment 8
 |
[load more]
 |
comment 10
```

For that I need my `comments` document to be numbered (to know if there is more comments to load between two comments) according to their creation time.

Thing is, since cloud functions trigger are asynchronous, there is no real way for me to index incoming documents based on creation time.

For example, one document created a few ms after another might trigger the cloud function earlier and therefore cause an error in the index.

The only solution I can think of now is, for each incoming `comment`, run a query of the number of `comments` in the collection that have a timestamp inferior to this one and use that as the index. But this is obviously not really viable in terms of cost/performance.

How would you approach this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the creation timestamp of the comment in the function itself, not on the client.  Then you still get time based ordering without having to require the client to synchronize the document write immediately.

Comment: Thanks! I added an answer using your suggestion, would love your input on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from Doug to turn the problem backward and assign the index BEFORE assigning the timestamp in the cloud function in order to ensure index order I came up with the following code:

```dart
  const { post_id, text } = data;

  return db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(post_id);
    const postComDocRef = postDocRef.collection('comments').doc();

    const postDoc = await transaction.get(postDocRef);
    if (!postDoc.exists)
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found',
        `Post ${post_id} not found.`
      );
    try {
      const comments_count = postDoc.data()!.comments_count;
      transaction.update(postDocRef, {
        comments_count: comments_count + 1
      });
      transaction.create(postComDocRef, {
        author: context.auth!.uid,
        text,
        index: comments_count,
        created_at: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', `Transaction failed.`);
    }
  });
```

It uses a transaction to get an atomic value of the current count of comments already made, then use that value as the comment index before assigning the corresponding timestamp

Comment: I wouldn't bother with an index here. Cloud functions can run out of order, so I would just accept the ordering by timestamp.

Comment: @DougStevenson The explicit index is needed here for the lazy loading on the client. I need to know if there is more comments to load between a comment and another. I can do that by comparing the indexes of the two comments

Comment: Firestore has a pagination API that makes these indexes mostly unnecessary.

Comment: @DougStevenson Even by using a cursor, I still need to know if there is some data to query in the range. I could do a query in that range and count the results, but that would kind of go against the lazy loading approach here

Comment: I guess I don't understand this requirement to load arbitrary ranges of indexed comments, but if this works for you, run with it.